# Need to count certain values from a list in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to count a specific value on a list that is made with string values and show the result in another cell on another tab. So long, I tried with `=COUNTUNIQUE("C", TABNAME!F2:F124)` but I guess the spreadsheet don't consider the value a string. How can I arrange the formula so it takes the value C in the list.

These are the values of the list:

[image: values of the list]

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE({"C"; TABNAME!F2:F124})
```